# Does the symmetric group $S_{n+m}$ have a subgroup isomorphic to $S_n\times S_m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

> Does the symmetric group $S_{n+m}$ have a subgroup isomorphic to $S_n\times S_m$?

What I've been trying is just manually trying to find a subgroup that's isomorphic to $S_n\times S_m$, but I was wondering if I could use one of the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: There are at least $\binom{n+m}n$ such subgroups.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not if $n=m=1$...

Comment: And if $n=m>1$ we still overcount the subgroups because each of them has more than one isomorphism with $S_n\times S_m$.

Comment: Yep, you are correct, @Troposphere There are (at least) $\binom{n+m}n$ distinct embeddings of $S_n\times S_m,$ but the images of the embeddings do not give unique subgroups when $n=m.$ Missed that.

Comment: The case pointed out by @Servaes is even worse, though, because the $\binom{1+1}{1}$ embeddings are not actually distinct as embeddings either.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 8):

The group $S_{n+m}$ can be realized as the group of bijections from the set $\{1,\ldots,m+n\}$ to itself. Now consider the subgroup of bijections that map the subsets $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $\{m+1,\ldots,m+n\}$ to themselves.

Comment: That has to be the fastest downvote ever; under 1 second! Care to explain?

Comment: Can’t say why - I’m not the downvoter. But some people downvote answers to questions where the question has shown little work.

Comment: I actually like this answer a lot, +1 from me

Comment: This was ver helpful! Thanks

Comment: The only possible reason for having downvoted  this was that it was seen as obvious. But to OP, it was clearly not obvious. Thank you.

Comment: This just slipped my mind. I was stupid - Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sets

$$S=\{\sigma\in S_{m+n}\mid \sigma(i)=i,\,\forall i\in\{m+1,m+2,\dots, m+n\}\}$$

and

$$T=\{\tau\in S_{m+n}\mid \tau(j)=j,\,\forall j\in\{1,2,\dots, m\}\}.$$

Clearly $S, T\le S_{m+n}$. Moreover, the elements of $S$ commute with the elements of $T$ and *vice versa*. Also $S\cong S_m$ and $T\cong S_n$. The (internal) direct product of two subgroups of a group is a subgroup of that group. It is routine to check, then, that $S\times T\cong S_m\times S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a group $G$, $H \cap K = \{e\}$, and every element of $H$ commutes with every elements of $K$, then $HK = \{ hk : h\in H, k \in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is isomorphic to the direct product $H \times K$.